# ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away. It looks like MySQL doesn't take the settings from the my.cnf file

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I want import a big file ( 10GB) in MySQL in Ubuntu
with this command: 
    `mysql -u root -p < name database> < path the the file to import`      .

Then I get this error: ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away

In my.cnf I added:
    `[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet=2048M`

Then I go to the MySQL console with 
      `mysql -u root -p`

Using:
      `Select @@global.max_allowed_packet;`
I see a much lower value as I wrote in my.cnf.

The value is still low after restarting the service with
      `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart`

When I use
    `SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=1073741824;`
in the MySQL console, THEN the max_allowed_packet value is changed.

After this I start
      `MySQL -u root -p < name database> < path the the file`
to import again. Now there is no error and the file is imported.

The mysql file is in
     '    /etc/mysql    ', the my.cnf file is also in
     '/etc/mysql'

It looks like MySQL doesn't take the settings from the my.cnf file.

Comment: You can get `my.cnf` files' addresses and reading order by using `mysql --help`.